# Unable to archive some messages

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

There are 3 old messages in my jobs inbox that I am unable to archive. No matter how many times I do it, individually or in bulk, they always reappear on refresh.

When I look at the Network tab, this is the API response, which looks like it should be working:

```json
{"success":true,"model":[3273559,3287680,3281163],"message":null}
```

Comment: Always tricky to Handle Success: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207388/why-is-the-handlesuccess-method-such-a-terrible-one